# Custom CSS not working for radio button selection FF/ IE

Tags: html, css, jsf-2.2

I am using custom css to style my radio buttons like as below:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    display: inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height: 19px;
    margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    outline:none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(70, 121, 189);
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

label{
    top: 0.2rem;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:74%;
    height:72%;
    margin: 11% auto;    
    border-radius:50%;    
}

input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    rgb(70, 121, 189);
}
```

With above CSS

> Checked Radio button color is changing in Chrome only but not in IE and FF and also dot is not properly centered.
>
> I do not want to use `input[type="radio"] + Label` style because ia m usnig JSF Radio buttons as below. "+label" CSS does not work here with JSF radio buttons :(

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{value.from.backing.bean}" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="active" itemLabel="#
      {text['from.property.file']}"  />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="active2" itemLabel="#
      {text['from.property.file']}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{backing.method}" render=":form"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

JS Fiddle here [Radio](https://jsfiddle.net/mfoe9bda/)

Any ideas pleasE?

Comment: whats the version of IE and FF you are using?

Comment: any versions.. on all versions m facing.. currently m using 36 FF and IE11

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the way of implement and

[Here is another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300659/pseudo-content-properies-varies-in-each-browsers) by me for myself and other developers in need ;)