# pseudo content properies varies in each browsers

Tags: html, css, radio-button, pseudo-element

I am using custom CSS to style radio boxes but now the problem is that

> checked radio circle is appearing at diff positions in IE11, FF36 and Chrome. Below is the illustration

[image]

CSS used to achieve this is as below:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    border:1px solid $grey;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\25CF";
    border:1px solid $light-blue;
    color: $light-blue;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0rem;
    padding-top: 7px;
}
```

Any ideas please to work it same in all browsers..

Comment: I'm gonna guess that this is something to do with the line height.

Comment: IE 9, 10 and 11 do not support rem units when used in the "line-height" property when used on :before and :after pseudo elements (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/776744).

Comment: Also check you are using `box-sizing:border-box`.

Comment: I guess it's a line height issues, try pixel instead of rem.

Comment: Value for line-height property is unitless and also 0 never needs an unit. You can check existing examples like the one from [Filament Group](https://github.com/filamentgroup/checkboxradio) or from my ex-colleague [CreativeJuiz](http://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/tutoriels/personnaliser-aspect-boutons-radio-checkbox-css) (in french but code should be enough).

Answer (score 1):

I changed the approach. Instead of using content and line height, i switched as below

```
label:before {
content: "";
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
position: absolute;
padding:1px;
left: 0;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius: 50px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
border:1px solid blue;
background-color:blue;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff inset;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgnhoamL/)

Comment: anybody need can use this solution ;)